# Learning Selenium and I have some questions about locating a specific xpath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I'm trying to play around with elements on Reddit but after searching I am unable to select the 'View More' element. I don't have much experience working with the framework and I thought I understood Xpaths but I am unable to figure out where I'm going wrong

I am revising Xpaths right now and will post if I find a solution myself.

Here's an image to hopefully make things clearer:
[image]

Here are the paths I have tried:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//class='s13lw6dy-6 cOyQoR']//*[text()='View more']")).Click();
```

I am using the following imports:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
```

Comment: What's unclear about what's being asked?  He simply wants to locate an element by xPath.  It's a basic question, but seems crystal clear to me and we got the right answer below.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe it was my title, I have amended it now :D @C.Peck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right-click the HTML element and click 'Inspect,' you can get an Xpath for that element in the page. You should be able use that in your selenium code, if it isn't dynamic (doesn't change from one page load to another).

[image: Reddit search: 'View More' button in Chrome Inspector]

```
xpath = "//*[@id="SHORTCUT_FOCUSABLE_DIV"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/a"

button = find_element_by_xpath(xpath)

# another possible xpath:
# button = find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'View more')]")

button.click()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful! I guess the structure of my xpath was off! Really appreciate the help!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help!

Comment: Is it possible to chain xpaths together like this .//*[@class='s7pq5uy-0 fuUbHU']//*[@class='s13lw6dy-6 cOyQoR']//*[text()='View more']? @Richard

Comment: I'm not sure. I would try it out and see what happens. What end result are you trying to achieve?

Comment: To throw my two cents in here, what Richard indicates as "another possible xpath" is WAY more reliable way to identify the element.  In the first example, practically any change to the CSS on the page (which will happen regularly on a site like reddit).  Speaking of which, I'm a little curious what workflow you want to automate on Reddit...

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to find any excuse to just try and locate elements with Xpath as it seems like the most viable way when working with sites like facebook and reddit. I wanted to try dealing with a list of objects as I haven't had any experience doing that. Are there any exercises you guys might recommend?

Comment: The script opens Reddit, signs in, redirects to https://www.reddit.com, selects the search bar and uses a function I made to search for a subreddit (This is passed as an argument), it expands the search result, creates an IList to store the returned subreddits, searches the IList for "r/apexlegends" (for example) and then opens the subreddit. If the subreddit doesn't exist, then it will just click the first item in the list. @C.Peck

Comment: Sure, I can see what the script does, just wondering why you want to do it.  Just for practice?